# How to highlight code AutoIt in Blogger?

Tags: highlight

I am using Google Blogger and would like to use syntax highlighting for code.

I tried a couple of ways, but I'm not satisfied with the results.

AutoIt Code is not supported in JavaScript.

Can anyone share how they have done it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you here of Highlight.js ? It's good.

[Highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/)

[Quickstart Demo](http://southstreamserbia-dotnet-pipe.blogspot.de/2015/03/highlightjs-v84-code-formatter.html)

Comment: The new version has support!
Thank you very much!